# align apex fields in vf page adapting lightning style

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am trying to incorporate LDS stylesheets in my vf page and opening the page in Classic view , what i see that is a horizontal scroll bar due to the size of input fields being too long and occupying the whole browser window as you can in see in the picture , is there a way i can size and align my fields so that i doesnt take all of the salesforce window screen , so that the user can avoid scrolling the horizontal bar ?

[image]

```
<div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                <h3 class="slds-section__title">

                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Section Title">Co-Borrower Information</span>
                    </button>-->
                    <span class="slds-section__title-action slds-truncate" title="Co-Borrower Information">Co-Borrower Information</span>
                </h3>


                <fieldset class="slds-form--compound slds-is-editing">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__group">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__row">

                            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2">
                                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Co Borrower First Name</label>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:inputField id="coBorFirstName" value="{!Lead.Co_Borrower_First_Name__c}" styleClass="slds-input"/>    
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2">
                                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Co Borrower Last Name</label>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:inputField id="coBorLastName" value="{!Lead.Co_Borrower_Last_Name__c}" styleClass="slds-input" showDatePicker="true"/>    
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="slds-form--compound slds-is-editing">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__group">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__row">

                            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2">
                                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Co Borrower Birthdate</label>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:inputField id="coBorBirthDate" value="{!Lead.Co_Borrower_Birthdate__c}" showDatePicker="true" styleClass="dateClass dateOnlyInput input"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>  


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>


            </div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide details as to what you have tried?

Comment: Might sound silly, but can you try wrapping everything in a `div class="slds"` tag?